# Rails routing sometimes confuses method for object ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, object, methods

So I have a rails app with a controller that has a bunch of methods. For some reason occasionally calls to this controller have not been interpreted correctly by the app. For example:

```
    A 404 error occurred on the Production server at 2016-07-28 02:55:23 UTC:
Message:

Problem: Document(s) not found for class Section with id(s) publish_preview. Summary: When calling Section.find ... [etc.]

Requested Params

    {"action"=>"update", "controller"=>"sections", "organization_id"=>"goannunciation", "bulletin_id"=>"20160731", "id"=>"publish_preview"}

Url:

bulletinbuilder.org/organizations/goannunciation/bulletins/20160731/sections/publish_preview
```

So the sections controller has a "publish_preview" method, which this URL is supposed to--and usually does--call appropriately. However, recently the app has not interpreted the URL correctly; from the stack:

```
"/var/www/bulletin_builder/releases/20160725175809/app/controllers/sections_controller.rb:34:in `update'"
```

which indicates that the app is calling the "update method," using the actual method call "publish_preview" as the id of the section. This must be some kind of routing error... possibly related to the header? Browser related?

```
 resources :organizations do
  ...
  resources :bulletins do
   ...
   resources :sections do
    collection do
      get :manage
      get :first_section
      get :bulletin_creation
      get :included_sections
      get :custom_sections_max_message
      get :search
      get :publish_preview
      get :admin_diagnostics
    end
    member do
      post :remove
      post :removed_blocked_section
      get :delete_dynamic
      get :update_included
      get :update_added
      get :share
      get :unshare
      get :refresh
    end
  end
```

As I mentioned in the comment below, the pertinent routes HAVE NOT been changed, and the issue only happens occasionally.

In addition, the server for some reason is sending a bunch (17) of error notification emails for the same error, all within a few seconds of each other.

Comment: can you please post your routes for this specific controller

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely related to the HTTP method being used to access the resource. For example,

```
GET /organizations/../sections/publish_preview
```

Will hit the `publish_preview` action as expected; however

```
PUT/POST /organizations/../sections/publish_preview
```

Will hit the `update` action with `:id` as `publish_preview`

If you're actually using the update action, you can add a constraint to only route numeric ids

```
resources :sections, constraints: { id: /\d+/} do
  ...
end
```

If you're not using the update action, just remove the update route

```
resources :sections, except: [:update]
```

There are other ways to handle this too but the above two are probably the easiest to implement depending on your case.

Comment: That makes sense... the methods were recently changed to handle sending a large amount of data.

However, the method WAS NOT changed for the "manage" method, and that one has been giving us issues as well. And why is it inconsistent? Seems like I should be able to rely on rails to look first to see if the URL is calling a method, and if not THEN assume it's a CRUD function...

Comment: Actually, none of the HTTP methods in the section routes were changed, though they were in some other areas recently.

Comment: It isn't inconsistent. Rails will route a request depending on the rules defined in `routes.rb`. If you make a `PUT` request to `../sections/publish_preview` it will *always* hit the `update` action because that's how you've defined the routes. I would look to see if there's anything in your code making the `PUT` request to that URL.

Answer (score 0):

So this was a very strange intermittent issue. It was kind of complex but it apparently boiled down to this:

There was a method that called a bunch of other methods. Some of those methods were put in a separate thread because they took a while to run. The enclosing method sometimes ended with a "return_to :back" before the thread calling the other methods was completed.

This apparently did some funky things to the app, including messing with the params used in the running thread, and causing some really strange errors. The issue was solved by replacing the return_to :back with a render json: statement.